# Zoom Button on JIT Rgraph

Tags: javascript, infovis

While using R graph(Javascript Infovis Toolkit) I found only mouse wheel can be used as zoom in and out. Can any one help me with how I may control the graph with two buttons instead of mouse wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for the Force directed variant for graph named

You can change the .zooming value as provided in the example, in this one I set it to 15 and it zooms fairly slowly. 
fd:

```
function zoom(delta)
{
     if (fd) 
     {
          var val = fd.controller.Navigation.zooming/1000; 
          var ans = 1 - (delta * val);
          fd.canvas.scale(ans, ans);
     }    
}
```